# Issue with product js prestashop 1.6.1.16

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I got some issue if i switch between sizes, the price is not changing and in the console i have these errors from product.js - I use Prestashop 1.6.1.16.

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: productPrice is not defined
    at updateDisplay (product.js:425)
    at findCombination (product.js:419)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (linkname.html:824)
product.js:425 Uncaught ReferenceError: productPrice is not defined
    at updateDisplay (product.js:425)
    at findCombination (product.js:419)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (product.js:191)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3)
```

My product.js link here:Pastebin: [product.js](https://pastebin.com/Lm3rygPy)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom theme, make sure that the lines below are in your *product.tpl* file :

```
{if !$priceDisplay || $priceDisplay == 2}
    {assign var='productPrice' value=$product->getPrice(true, $smarty.const.NULL, 6)}
    {assign var='productPriceWithoutReduction' value=$product->getPriceWithoutReduct(false, $smarty.const.NULL)}
{elseif $priceDisplay == 1}
    {assign var='productPrice' value=$product->getPrice(false, $smarty.const.NULL, 6)}
    {assign var='productPriceWithoutReduction' value=$product->getPriceWithoutReduct(true, $smarty.const.NULL)}
{/if}
```

and

```
{addJsDef productPriceWithoutReduction=$productPriceWithoutReduction|floatval}
{addJsDef productPrice=$productPrice|floatval}
```

You can compare your *product.tpl* file and the one in the default-bootstrap theme to make sure that there isn't any other variables missing.